# I'm having some difficulty understanding [basic.scope.pdecl]/7

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, forward-declaration

[[basic.scope.pdecl]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#7):

> The point of declaration of a class **first** declared in an
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> (7.1)   for a declaration of the form
>
> *class-key* *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier* `;`
>
> the *identifier* is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that contains the declaration,           otherwise
>
> (7.2)   for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> *class-key* *identifier*
>
> if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq*
>   or
>            *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace
>   scope, the *identifier* is
>            declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that contains the declaration; otherwise,
>            except as a friend
>   declaration, the *identifier* is declared in the smallest namespace or
>            block scope that contains the declaration. [ Note: These rules also apply within templates.
>             — end note ] [ Note: Other forms of *elaborated-type-specifier* do not declare a new
>            name, and therefore must refer to an existing *type-name*. See [basic.lookup.elab] and
>            [dcl.type.elab].— end note ]

Consider the case (7.2) above where the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope. How would that conciliate with the fact that this *elaborated-type-specifier* must be the **first** declaration of the class in its namespace?

Consider the example ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ACn2lgRqN8hZJA0i)) below:

File `prog.cc`:

```
struct S;
extern S s;
int S;
void f(struct S&);     // The elaborated-type-specififer `struct S` is not
                       // the first declaration in the global namespace and
                       // if we eliminate the first declaration `struct S;` 
                       // on the top, the code doesn't compile !!
int main(){
    f(s);
}
```

File `other.cc`:

```
#include<iostream>
struct S{
    int i = 1;
};
void f(struct S& s) { std::cout << s.i << '\n'; }
S s;
```

Note that the code above compiles and executes correctly, but the *elaborated-type-specififer* in the *parameter-declaration-clause* of function `f` is not the first in the global namespace.

Assuming that my interpretation about [basic.scope.pdecl]/7 is correct, I would like to see an example showing the application of paragraph (7.2) above, where the alluded declaration would be the **first** in its namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if we eliminate the first declaration `struct S;` on the top, the code doesn't compile !!

Well that's because you still need to declare a name before you use it.

```
int S;
void f(struct S&); 
extern struct S s; // If you write this line before then it
                   // will not compile.
                   // The name still needs to be declared
                   // before you use it.
// If you drop the `int S` above, then the following
// will also compile, since S has already been declared
// extern S s2;

int main(){
    f(s);
}
```

> Note that the code above compiles and executes correctly, but the *elaborated-type-specififer* in the *parameter-declaration-clause* of function `f` is not the first in the global namespace.

I don't understand the point you're trying to make here. Since it's not the first, no name is declared and [basic.scope.pdecl]p7 doesn't apply.

> I would like to see an example showing the application of paragraph (7.2) above, where the alluded declaration would be the first in its namespace.

```
auto addrof(struct S& s) { // First declaration
    return &s;
}
int get(struct T&); // First declaration
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't think about the `extern S s;` after the declaration `void f(struct S&);`, although your example still needs a minor correction: you have to declare the `extern` declaration as `extern struct S s;` instead, for the code to compile. To clarify, my point was that it would be impossible to make my example to compile without the declaration `struct S;` at the top of the file `prog.cc` and you showed me that is not true, by moving the declaration `extern S s;` after the function declaration. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have another question for you regarding my example and the fact that `extern S s;` doesn't compile after the function declaration. Now after reading more carefully [basic.scope.pdecl]/(7.2) I found this: "the identifier is declared as a _class-name_ in the namespace that contains the declaration;" which seems to indicate that your code **should** compile even without applying the correction suggested by me on my previous comment. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Ayrosa that part only applies to function definitions, but either way, no without your correction it doesn't work because name lookup finds both the *class-name* `S` and the *unqualified-id* `S`. [They're not the same entity](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#1.sentence-3).

Comment: Never mind. The `struct` is necessary in `extern struct S s;` because of the declaration `int S;`. If we eliminate this declaration, the code compiles with `extern S s;` as you mentioned initially.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to see an example showing the application of paragraph (7.2) above, where the alluded declaration would be the first in its namespace.

Simply:

```
namespace ns {
    // declares S into ns as per [basic.scope.pdecl]
    void f(struct S&);
}

extern ns::S s;
//extern ::S s; // not declared
```

Here `struct S` is first declared in the elaborated-type-specifier in a parameter-declaration-clause of a function defined in namespace scope, with the form `class-key identifier`, and therefore [basic.scope.pdecl]/7.2 applies and `struct S` is declared in the namespace `ns` where the function is declared.

> you'll have to use an object of class `S` in your function `f`

Here is an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95c2c99d6bd7a38a):

```
// ... continuing from previous example ...
namespace ns {
    struct S {
        int i;
    };

    void f(S& s) {
        std::cout << s.i;
    }
}
```

---

As a bonus, an example where the class is not first declared in the elaborated-type-specifier, and so the quoted rule does not apply:

```
struct S;
namespace ns {
    void f(struct S&); // refers to ::S
}

//extern ns::S s; // not declared
extern ::S s;
```

Here, the elaborated-type-specifier is not the first declaration of `struct S`, so [basic.scope.pdecl]/7 does not apply, and no class is declared into the namespace.

Comment: To prove your point you'll have to use an object of class `S` in your function `f`, maintaining the elaborated-type-specifier `struct S` as its first declaration in namespace `ns`.

Comment: @Ayrosa it's unclear to me what point it proves, but I've added an example for you.

Comment: In your example, `void f(S&)` doesn't contain an _elaborated-type-specifier_.

Comment: @Ayrosa It doesn't need to. `S` has already been declared in the line `void f(struct S&);`.

Comment: I'm talking about your second example.

Comment: @Ayrosa Yes. The second example extends the first.

Comment: @eerorika Your example didn't convince me either. Why don't you show an executing code, that prints the value of a member from an object of class S, in function f?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso I didn't show such code, since I didn't think it could be relevant to the question. I've now modified the example to show that. Could you specify what you find unconvincing?

Comment: Your example still does not prove your point. An optimizing compiler would eliminate your _original-namespace-definition_ and the code would compile and execute normally, but now you wouldn't have the _elaborated-type-specifier_ `struct S` as the first declaration in namespace `ns`. In other words, so far your _original-namespace-definition_  serves no purpose in answering my question.

Comment: @Ayrosa It's unclear to me what point you are imagining me trying to make. My point is that `extern ns::S s` is well-formed (see the first example). It is well-formed because of the rule [basic.scope.pdecl]/7.2 and the earlier declaration `void f(struct S&)`; thus the example is what you asked for in the question. Optimisations do not change the declarations. `struct S` is an elaborated-type-specifier regardless of optimisations.

Comment: The code in you first declaration of namespace `ns` is dummy. I'm pretty sure that the intent of [basic.scope.pdecl](7.2) was not to justify a code like yours, which will never be used, by any compiler.

Comment: @Ayrosa What do you mean by *"dummy"*? Why do you think that no compiler would use it? I haven't seen the justification for the rule. I doubt that nothing important would have been lost if for example it would be required that elaborated-type-specififers referred only to existing declarations  - other than compatibility with C. Which I would agree is a good reason for the rule to exist.